# starting a label on a new line each time its variable changes? (Python Tkinter module)

Tags: python, tkinter, server, client, messaging

I made a program that lets you send and receive messages to/from a server. The program itself works but my problem is with the tkinter. I want to make the program GUI but each time a message is received from the server, it overwrites the variable and the label shows only the new message. Is there a way where the old messages are somehow saved like in real text messaging apps so that it shows all the messages and not the latest one?

Here's a picture:

[image: picture of what I want]

```
def receiving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                print(data)
                label1 = Label(root, text = data).grid(row = 1, column = 0,
                                                       sticky = W)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()
```

Comment: I would consider using a Listbox and adding each received message at the end of the list

Comment: Instead of a `Label` widget, you could insert new messages to the end of a `Text` widget (which can have [`Scrollbar`](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm)s attached to it).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use grid like you do, because `label1 = Label(root, text = data).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)` will give you a `None` for `label1`. You are not returning a instance of `Label.`
Like suggested in the comments you can use a Textwidget or another widget.

But if you want to use Label, your only problem is that you overlap the Labels if you use the same row over and over again.

```
def receiving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                rowcounter = 1
                print(data)
                tmp_label = Label(root, text = data)
                tmp_label.grid(row = rowcounter, column = 0, sticky = W)
                rowcounter += 1
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()
```

But this approach may overlap your other widgets if you use them in the same Frame.